# Получить список ключей из словаря

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари

Нужно получить все ключи словаря в виде списка. Функция `keys()` возвращает `dict_keys(['a', 'b']`. Пожалуйста, подскажите, как быть?

Справка из интернета:

> Python 3
> Для обхода ключей создаётся представление ключей словаря, по сути являющееся генератором. Копия данных не создаётся.

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}.keys()  # dict_keys(['a', 'b'])
```

> Python 2
> Для обхода ключей создаётся копия данных словаря.

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}.keys()  # ['a', 'b']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что бы получить из

```
dict_keys(['a', 'b'])
```

строку, достаточно применить list(), пример

```
list(dict_keys(['a', 'b']))
```

нашел на просторах overflow

Answer (score 9):

```
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
print(list(d.keys()))  # ['a', 'b']

# Или просто:
print(list(d))  # ['a', 'b']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ke = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
print([i for i in ke])
# ['a', 'b']
```

Или

```
ke = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
print([i for i, j in ke.items()])
# ['a', 'b']
```